# Logstash does not update @timestamp from apache log

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

If you are backfilling logs into logstash you are supposed to try and pull somehow the proper timestamps. Otherwise they get assigned to the time the log line was received by logstash.

This is achieved using `date` filter like:

```
date { match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ] }
```

But unfortunately this does not work for me.

So i have the following apache logline:

```
10.80.161.251 - - [15/Oct/2015:09:13:45 +0000] "- -" "POST /xxx HTTP/1.1" 200 696 29416 "-" "xxx" 4026
```

And the following pattern

```
ACCESS_LOG %{IPORHOST:clientip} %{USER:ident} %{USER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:[@metadata][timestamp]}\] "(?:TLSv%{NUMBER:tlsversion}|-) (?:%{NOTSPACE:cypher}|-)" "(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes_in}|-) (?:%{NUMBER:bytes_out}|-) %{QS:referrer} %{QS:agent} %{NUMBER:tts}
```

And the following logstash config

```
# INPUTS
input {
    file {
        path => '/var/log/test.log'
        type => 'apache-access'
    }
}

# filter/mix/match
filter {
    if [type] == 'apache-access' {
        grok {
            patterns_dir => [ '/root/logstash-patterns' ]
            match => [ "message", "%{ACCESS_LOG}" ]
        }

        if !("_grokparsefailure" in [tags]) {
            mutate { add_field => ["timestamp_submitted", "%{@timestamp}"] }

            date {
                match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
            }
        }
    }
}

# now output
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

What i am doing wrong here. I tried adding timezones, locales and what not. And it still does not work. Any help is greatly appreciated (plus a drink of choice if you happen to be in sofia, bulgaria).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note to self: read more carefully**

The issue here is not matching against the proper field.

Because of the default pattern for apache logs the timestamp from the logline is in `[@metadata][timestamp]` and not in `timestamp`

So the date match filter should be:

```
date {
    match => [ "[@metadata][timestamp]", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
}
```